# UINavigationController animation choppy

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

In iOS 7, if the view controller being presented's view's background color is `[UIColor clearColor]`, the animation becomes really choppy/freezes half of the way there.

I am wondering if there's anyway around this?

Comment: Are you certain that the background color is the actual cause?  Have you tried changing nothing else but the color and seen different results?

Comment: @nhgrif yep, try it yourself. Push a view controller whose background color is set to clearColor and you'll see.

Comment: @0xSina I just tried it. It isn't slow or choppy, but it looks awful, the pushed view sits on top, and the back view just disappears instantly.

Comment: @Can yep that's what I meant. Choppy was the wrong word..it's just weird, that's what I meant.

Comment: I believe its a bug. Check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really interesting. I think, though, that it's not choppy at all: that's the actual animation a navigation controller is performing, and it just looks different because the pushed view controller has a clear view.

Consider two opaque view controllers in a similar situation (call them "A" and "B," for ease of reference). Give A a bunch of a content that spans the entire width of the view – I used most of the alphabet in a label. Doesn't matter what content, just as long as you can see it and obviously tell how far it's gotten near the end of the animation.

Now push B. Right before it covers the entire screen, take a look at what part of A's content you can still see. You should find that A's content is not almost all the way offscreen like you might expect; instead, it's just shifted a little bit to the left. In my alphabet test, rather than seeing the tail end of a late letter like "w," I instead see a bit of "g" peeking out. A only shifted a six or seven letters' worth:

[image: Before the transition]
[image: Near the end of the transition (note the g)]

The same thing is happening here with your clear pushed view. The underlying opaque view moves, but not all the way off the edge of the screen; instead, it shifts just enough to give the viewer the impression of motion, then sits there until the transition finishes. After that, it can be removed from the view hierarchy (since it's in theory no longer visible) and so disappears.

You can circumvent this kind of behavior by using the iOS 7 view controller transitioning APIs. See, for example, the [objc.io article about them](http://www.objc.io/issue-5/view-controller-transitions.html) or the [WWDC session videos](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/) for more info. You'll wind up reimplementing the entire slide transition, though, and may need to do your own work to support the swipe-to-go-back gesture as well.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed/thorough response!

Answer (score 0):

I, too, confronted this issue. I found a fix via a custom animation at:

https://gist.github.com/ArtFeel/7690431